# Error when installing desktopvideo 10.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, video

I've got a new Blackmagic Decklink 4k extreme video capture card. I'm trying to get it run on a Dell T5810 with an Intel Xeon E5-1620 CPU and Ubuntu 14.04 running on it.

I've tried to install desktopvideo 10.4.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 but always run in the same error message. I get the same errors with the newest desktopvideo version 10.5.

I've tried to install it with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i desktopvideo_10.4.3a5_amd64.deb
```

But it fails to build the modules as shown in the report:

```
Preparing to unpack desktopvideo_10.4.3a5_amd64.deb ...
Stopping upstart services...
  DesktopVideoHelper (failed)
Unloading modules...
Removing old drivers...
  blackmagic
Unpacking desktopvideo (10.4.3a5) over (10.4.3a5) ...
Setting up desktopvideo (10.4.3a5) ...
Preparing new blackmagic driver for 3.13.0-63-generic kernel...
  Adding to DKMS
  Building (failed)
Preparing new blackmagic-io driver for 3.13.0-63-generic kernel...
  Adding to DKMS
  Building (failed)
Loading modules...
Starting upstart services...
  DesktopVideoHelper
********************************************************************************
Failed to build driver(s)

Possible causes:
 1. Driver is incompatible with your kernel version
 2. Kernel headers/gcc/make/etc. is not installed
 3. Kernel header version does not match the running kernel (3.13.0-63-generic)

Error messages:
dkms build -m blackmagic -v 10.4.3a5 
---

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-63-generic KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-63-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 97, in <module>
    with open(apport.fileutils.make_report_path(report), 'wb') as f:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_report_path'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-63-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/make.log for more information.

dkms build -m blackmagic-io -v 10.4.3a5 
---

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-63-generic KERNELRELEASE=3.13.0-63-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 97, in <module>
    with open(apport.fileutils.make_report_path(report), 'wb') as f:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_report_path'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-63-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic-io/10.4.3a5/build/make.log for more information.


********************************************************************************
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

The make.log looks like this:

```
DKMS make.log for blackmagic-10.4.3a5 for kernel 3.13.0-63-generic (x86_64)
Mon Sep 21 10:56:02 CEST 2015
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-63-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic_serial.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic_core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic_lib.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic_dma.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic_gate.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic.o
ld: Relocatable linking with relocations from format elf64-x86-64 (/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/bmd-support.a) to format elf32-i386 (/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic.o) is not supported
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build/blackmagic.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/blackmagic/10.4.3a5/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

When I check the status of the kernel module afterwards it shows that it is added, but not installed

```
dkms status -m blackmagic -k `uname -r`
```

Anyone run in a similar problem or has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with `linux-generic`

While I had the headers for the newest kernel version

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-63
linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic 
linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
```

But I missed the more general headers

```
linux-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-generic
```

I have no idea how they got lost, it was a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04. Therefore I assume they should have been installed. The installation worked fine after I manually installed the linux-generic

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```